# cannot alter table to add a foreign key

Tags: sql, alter

```
alter table course_relation
add foreign key (offered_By)
references department_relation(dept_cd)

alter table department_relation
add foreign key(hod)
references staff_relation(staff_no)

alter table staff_relation
add foreign key (dept_cd)
references department_relation(dept_cd)
```

//the third para doesn't work but the first two works fine
error message:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 10 The ALTER TABLE statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__staff_rela__dept__1BC821DD". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Royal_Poly_DB", table "dbo.Department_Relation", column 'Dept_Cd'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create circular foreign key references.

In this Statement

```
  alter table department_relation
  add foreign key(hod)
  references staff_relation(staff_no)
```

In this alter query you create foreign key reference in 'department_relation' from 'staff_relation' table.

```
alter table staff_relation
add foreign key (dept_cd)
references department_relation(dept_cd)
```

In this alter query you create foreign key reference in 'staff_relation' from 'department_relation' table.

This is circular dependency of foreign key and it is allowed.